# SqlMetal is ignoring one association

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

I'm using SqlMetal to generate a map of the DB in C# against the developing environment DB. The generated file has 1,89MB.

```
SqlMetal /server:<ip> /database:<dbname> /user:<dbuser> /password:<pass> /code:DBO.cs /namespace:<namespace>
```

In order to have more recent data on the developing environment I backup the production environment DB and restore it to the developing machine.

Now, when I run the script that uses SqlMetal, there's one association that SqlMetal chooses to ignore.

I have `TableA` with 9 FK, it only generates 8 Associations for that table. The association between `TableA` and `TableB` is missing.

Worse that that is that associations between other tables and `TableB` are working fine.

Any idea why it's only skipping associations between `tableA` and `tableB`?

**Edit**

`TableB` is called `user`. Maybe this happens because the table name is a sql reserved word.